# Anroid LinearLayout con divisores diagonales

Tags: android

Tengo una consulta. Necesito implementar una vista con 3 imágenes (que representan como 3 opciones), divididas horizontalmente. Pero están dividas a través de una diagonal de X grados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Habrá alguna forma de hacerlo?
Gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y lee 
[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Por favor [edit] tu pregunta agregando qué has intentado hasta el momento.

Comment: Creo que la opción mas rápida es crear tu propia vista, como lo indica el tutorial de android en su [sitio oficial](https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html). Ahora mismo no tengo mucho tiempo para poner código así que solo comento.

Answer (score 0):

Hasta el día de hoy (API 25) no es posible crear una vista que tenga un lado inclinado como el que comentas.

Depende del diseño que deseas pero como opción podrías simular esto con una imagen que haga suponer es parte de la vista que se encuentra a su derecha, marco con color rojo la imagen que sería rectangular:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]